# Any idea why firefox not showing bold words?

Tags: 12.10, firefox

As you can see in this picture firefox doesn't show any word that is **bold**:

[image]

As you can see the some lines are not shown properly. For example first line of search result is :

> How to Make________________4___________________3

which normally should be:

> How to Make **Firefox** 4 Look Like **Firefox** 3

Here is another picture:

[image]

This is is more inconvenient, title in top of the page, menus in left side of the page, and some titles and menus in context are missing.

I already remove it and install again, still not working. 
Any idea would be appreciated.
I have 12.10 installed (if it matters). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question or problem here.  Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @mdpc: I think the problem is obvious: the bits of text on the web pages are supposed to be in bold, but Firefox for some reason is not displaying them.

Comment: Have you installed any fonts recently, or modified Firefox's fonts' settings?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I just changed the font settings.

In Preferences, Content, Fonts & Colors, Advanced, I unchecked

> Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selection above.

and it's normal again.

Comment: Interesting outcome of that change. I'm curious what were your selections then?

Comment: @Seth: isn't that obvious?

Comment: @Mehdi  I don't understand.  Isn't what obvious?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to look like? Assuming that you want it to acquire the same look as other applications, perform the following steps:-

1. Download: [User Chrome override file for Firefox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45326422/userChrome.css)
2. You will see a directory (folder) in your home folder/.mozilla/firefox which consists of letters and/or numbers. Create a directory named "chrome" within that directory.
3. Copy the downloaded file to the newly-created "chrome" directory.
4. If you have KDE installed, in the application preferences within System Settings, make sure that GTK applications are set to use the proper GTK icon theme you want. You can also prevent GTK applications looking like KDE ones by changing the GTK theme within KDE's System Settings and/or turning off the option to apply KDE colours to non-KDE applications, but this will make GTK applications look out of place in KDE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try changing your Firefox font in Preferences, Content, Fonts & Colors, Advanced.